# ¿Como hago para abrir un JFrame solo si se cerro un JDialog?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, interfaz-gráfica

```
private void button_LoadProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    AccesoRoot a = new AccesoRoot(this, true);
    a.setVisible(true);
    while (a.isVisible()) {

    }
    try {
        LoadProduct lp = new LoadProduct();
        lp.setVisible(true);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainStock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    this.dispose();
}
```

La idea de esto es que cuando se aprete el boton, le abra una ventana donde le pide usuario y contraseña, y esta ultima se cierra solo si se ingresaron bien los datos. Una vez que eso sucede, ahi se abre el JFrame, y la manera que lo solicione es con un `while (a.isVisible()) {}`

La pregunta es si ¿se puede hacer de otra forma?, me parece poco practico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te muestro un ejemplo de eliminación que te pide una confirmación y después se realiza una acción.

Puedes usar esto para saber si se cerró correctamente el `JDialog`.

```
private void btnEliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    int confirmation = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Se perderán los datos permanentemente", "Advertencia", 0, 2);
    if (confirmation == 0) {
        //Aquí sabes que se cerró correctamente
    }
}
```

Comment: Genial, gracias!